# Warning when saving plots in loop using Matplotlib

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, warnings

When I run the following code it warns after each loop iteration:

> ../matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:181: Warning: Source ID X was not found when attempting to remove it

If i remove the plt.close("all") that I thought was the cause, after 20 iterations it will instead say

> RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory.

And after it will show the first warning for each ID anyway

```
    dir_output_path = '/aPath'
    dir_data = '/data'

    pathlist = Path(dir_data).rglob('*.log.parq')

    iter = 0
    for path in pathlist:
    
        # because path is object not string
        path_in_str = str(path)
        df = pd.read_parquet(path_in_str)
    
        df.plot(x="column", y=["aColumn", "anotherColumn"])
    
        # I save plot to .png
        plt.savefig(dir_output_path + 'testPlot' + str(iter) + '.png' , bbox_inches='tight')
        iter += 1
        # If I don't include close it will instead warn 
        # after 20 plots that it might take up a lot of memory
        plt.close("all")
```

My best guess is that plt.savefig already removed the plots? This would then make the warning unnecessary, can I safely block this warning from being written to terminal?
I'm afraid I'm missing something here and I'll have issues when I scale this up.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error message with `matplotlib 3.5.1`. `plt.savefig` should not close the figure. You can test this by altering the figure and storing it again. So, the figure needs to be explicitly closed.

Comment: As an aside, `for iter, path in enumerate(pathlist):` provides you with the counter `iter` as well.